# Обработка коллизии только в том случае если палец на экране c++ sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

Проблема такова: написал код для перемещения шарика к пальцу на экране, но при добавлении коллизий произошли проблемы. Коллизия как бы работает, то только тогда когда на экране нет пальца. Когда он есть и я перемещаю объект, коллизия игнорируется. Вот код

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(360, 800), "SFML", Style::Default);
    Vector2u wSize = window.getSize();
    int centerX = wSize.x / 2;
    int centerY = wSize.y / 2;

    CircleShape shape(76.f, 30);
    shape.setFillColor(Color::Red);
    shape.setOrigin(shape.getRadius(), shape.getRadius());
    shape.setPosition(centerX, centerY);
    
    CircleShape shape2(76.f, 30);
    shape2.setFillColor(Color::Red);
    shape2.setOrigin(shape2.getRadius(), shape2.getRadius());
    shape2.setPosition(centerX, centerY / 2);

    float radiusSum = shape.getRadius() + shape2.getRadius();
    float radius = shape2.getRadius();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        unsigned int const idx{ 0 };
        sf::Vector2i rpos{ Touch::getPosition(idx, window) };
        Vector2f pos = window.mapPixelToCoords(rpos);

        // Обработка столкновений
        Vector2f distance = shape.getPosition() - shape2.getPosition();
        float length = std::sqrt(distance.x * distance.x + distance.y * distance.y);

        if (length < radiusSum)
        {
            // Обработка столкновения
            Vector2f collisionVector = distance / length;
            shape.setPosition(shape.getPosition() + collisionVector * (radiusSum - length));
        }

        if (::sf::Touch::isDown(idx))
        {
            if(shape.getGlobalBounds().contains(pos))
            {
            shape.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
            }
        }

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.draw(shape2);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так на блок `if (::sf::Touch::isDown(idx))`  обработка столкновения не оказывает никакого влияния. Что написали - то и получили.

Comment: Я немного совсем не понял что вы сказали